# Loading external JS file Asynchronously in document.ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I am trying to reference an external JS file asynchronously in document.read() event in application.

**What am I currently doing to achieve this?**

```
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.async = true;
    s.src = 'https://xxxx/jquery-3.2.1.js';
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
```

**My Question:**

Is there a better way to achieve the same thing with less lines of code using any other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, then you could use the `.getScript` function.

```
jQuery.getScript("https://xxxx/jquery-3.2.1.js");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you are doing it now is a good way of doing it. But if you want fewer lines of code and/or want the html you are adding to be more visible, you could do this.

```
var t = createElement("div");
t.innerHTML = '<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://xxxx/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>';
var x = document.querySelector("script");
x.parentNode.insertBefore(t.childNodes, x);
```

Comment: How about using Jquery? Can the "load" function in Jquery be used in this scenario? http://api.jquery.com/load/